# JPA Eclipse "Generating Tables From Entities" hangs forever

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink

On a Windows 8 64bit machine, in Eclipse Luna, I use JPA (EclipseLink 2.5.x) and Apache Derby as JDBC connection.

My persistence.xml so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ReportWriter" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.example.Clazz</class>
        <class>com.example.CommentBank</class>
        <class>com.example.CommentCategory</class>
        <class>com.example.CourseWork</class>
        <class>com.example.GradeModel</class>
        <class>com.example.Pupil</class>
        <class>com.example.PupilCoursework</class>
        <class>com.example.Report</class>
        <class>com.example.Year</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:D:\rwdb.db"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="rwdbuser"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="rwdbpassword"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.exclusive-connection.is-lazy" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Using the wizard, I created a new database connection in Eclipse which works pretty well.

When I want to do `JPA Tools` => `Generate Tables From Entities`, eclipse starts creating tables... and continues forever. There's no exception, no other message, it just blocks on this operation.

I cannot even cancel it. If I try to do so, it just adds "Cancel requested" to the item and keeps going. Closing eclipse isn't possible either, as it's awaiting the finish of its current operations.

`.metadata\.log` doesn't contain any new information about this.

Oh and I chose "sql-script" as output, just in case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes that should be generated already have to be listed in `persistence.xml`.
Once I did this, it worked.

Comment: classes are added in persistence.xml but hanging continues for me.

Answer (score -1):

The reason it takes forever is that the primary process is single-threaded and probably developed by someone using legacy style coding. Even if you have 8 CPUs, the process can only use a single thread and a limited amount of memory.